# Can there be a number which is provably larger than any number, yet is provably not infinite

Tags: elementary-number-theory, finitism, ultrafinitism

Suppose a natural number N.

Is it possible for this number to have the following properties:

1. The number is finite.
2. The number is greater than any other natural number.

Comment: What's your definition of *natural number*?

Comment: No, because (2) is impossible on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Under this assumption, $N+1$ is also a finite natural number, but $N+1>N$.